# Define a LAMBDA query in a property so it can be reused

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm trying to defined a lambda query in a property of my code first EF model as seen below as, `GetLatestTransaction` :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<TransactionModel> Transactions { get; set; }

    public TransactionModel GetLatestTransaction { 
        get {
            return Transactions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that I don't want to have to retype this query in many places and by having it in one place reduce the chances of a bug.

I want to use this in a query like this:

```
var user = _DB.Users
.Select(u => new UserDetailsView()
{
    Id = u.Id,
    FirstName= u.FirstName,
    LastName= u.LastName,
    Balance = u.GetLatestTransaction.ValueResult
}).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
```

This is however resulting in this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified type member 'GetLatestTransaction' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.'

Is there some way to achieve this without storing another relation to the latest transaction on the user and having to update it every time there is a new transaction?

**Edit:** I would also like to do it as above to avoid making another query to the database, I want it all in one go to improve performance.

Comment: Take a look at [NeinLinq](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq). It explains the problem and provides a one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your `ApplicationUser` class represents the table in the database. It does not represent the usage of the data in the table.

Quite a lot of people think it is good practice to separate the database structure from the usage of the data. This separation is quite often done using the repository pattern. The repository is an abstraction from the internal datastructure of the database. It allows you to add functionality to your classes without demanding this functionality in the control classes that communicate with the database.

There are numerous articles about the repository. [This one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repository-pattern-done-right) helped me to understand what functionality I should put in my entity framework classes and which in the repository.

So you'll need a class that represents the elements in your database table and one that represents the `applicationUsers` with only their `LatestTransaction`

The class that represents the database table:

```
class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TransactionModel> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser with the latest transaction

```
class AppicationUserExt : <base class needed?>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public TransactionModel LatestTransaction { get; set; }
}
```

The function to get your extended ApplicationUser is an extension function of your `ApplicationUser`. Input: `IQueryable<ApplicationUser` output: `IQueryable<ApplicationUserExt>`

```
static class MyDbContextExtensions
{
    // returns ne ApplicationUserExt for every ApplicationUser
    public IQueryable<ApplicationUserExt> ToExtendedUsers(this IQueryable<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers)
    {
        return applicationUsers
            .Select(user => new ApplicationUserExt()
            {
               Id = user.Id,
               FirstName = user.FirstName,
               LastName = user.LastName,
               LatestTransaction = user.Trnasactions
                   .OrderByDescenting(transaction => transaction.CreationDate)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever you have a query with the ApplicationUsers you want, you can use `ToExtendedUsers()` to get the extended suers

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    // you wanted to have a query like:
    var result dbContext.ApplicationUsers
        .Where(user => user.FirstName = "John"
                    && user.LastName = "Doe");

    // you'll have to add ToExtendedUsers:
    var result = dbContext.ApplicationUsers
        .Where(user => user.FirstName = "John"
                    && user.LastName = "Doe");
        .ToExtendedUsers();
}
```

As the result is still an IQueryable, no query has been done yet. You can still add LINQ statements before the query is done:

```
var result2 = result
    .Where(user.LatestTransaction.Year == 2018)        
    .GroupBy(user => user.LatestTransaction.Date)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

You see, that you can still do all kinds of LINQ stuff as long as it is an `ApplicationUser`. As soon as you need the `LatestTransaction` you convert it to an `ApplicationUserExt` and continue concatenating your linq statements.